# Django REST framework use AJAX url to point api detail url

Tags: python, ajax, django, datatables, django-rest-framework

I'm working on database program using Django. The program appends the database from user's forms/imported files, allows listing of data per category, and inline editing per category.

I did a lot of research (since i'm new in django), and so far I've been successful in generating forms, and and customized tables by combining rest framework and datatables.

The problem occurs when I tried to implement inline editing to my tables. I using the plugin datatables editor. My views and serializer seem to work since i can `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` in the Api Root. But then I can't make the ajax url point to the methods api detail views, I need the `pk`in the url to be variable to match the selection:

my serializer.py

```
class TankSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
modified_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', input_formats=None)
updated_by = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='last_name', queryset=User.objects.all())
pid = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='number', queryset=PID.objects.all())
zone = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='number', queryset=ProcessZone.objects.all())
medium = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='code', queryset=Medium.objects.all())
revision = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='code', queryset=Revision.objects.all())
supplier = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=Supplier.objects.all())
po = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='number', queryset=PO.objects.all())
material = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=Material.objects.all())

DT_RowId = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_DT_RowId(self, tank):
    return 'row_%d' % tank.pk

class Meta:
    model = Tank
    fields = (
        'DT_RowId', 'tag', 'description', 'pid', 'zone', 
        'medium', 'revision', 'supplier', 'po', 'material', 
        'volume', 'hight','modified_date','updated_by', 'created_by'
    )
```

my views.py

```
@login_required
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def edit_tanks(request, project_code):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, code=project_code)
    return render(request, 'edit_tanks.html', {'project': project})

class TankViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tank.objects.all().order_by('tag')
    serializer_class = TankSerializer
    lookup_filed = 'pk'

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=True)   
    def get(self, request, pk, project_code, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(self.queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=True)
    def post(self, request, pk=None, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @action(methods=['patch'], detail=True)
    def patch(self, request, pk, format=None):
        queryset = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @action(methods=['put'], detail=True)
    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        queryset = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @action(methods=['delete'], detail=True)
    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        queryset = self.get_object(pk)
        queryset.delete()
        return Response(status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

my urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'edit_tanks', views.TankViewSet, 'edit_tanks')

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^projects/(?P<project_code>\d+)/engineering/equipment/edit_tanks/api/', include(router.urls)),
    re_path(r'^projects/(?P<project_code>\d+)/engineering/equipment/edit_tanks/$', views.edit_tanks, name='edit_tanks'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

my template edit_tanks.html

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <table id="edit_tanks" class="stripe row-border order-column" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: auto; width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Tag</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>PID</th>
                <th>Zone</th>
                <th>Medium</th>
                <th>Revision</th>
                <th>Supplier</th>
                <th>PO</th>
                <th>Material</th>
                <th>Volume</th>
                <th>Height</th>
                <th>Last updated</th>
                <th>Updated by</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block extra_js %}

<script type="text/javascript">


var editor;

$(document).ready(function() {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {

        ajax: {
            create: {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'api/edit_tanks/?format=datatables',
            },
            edit: {
                type: 'PUT',
                url: 'api/edit_tanks/{{tank_pk}}/',
            },
            remove: {
                type: 'DELETE',
                url: 'api/edit_tanks/{{tank_pk}}/',
            }
        },

        table: "#edit_tanks",
        fields: [ {
                label: "Tag:",
                name: "tag"
            }, {
                label: "Description:",
                name: "description"
            }, {
                label: "Ravision:",
                name: "revision.code",
                type: "select"
            }, {
                label: "PO:",
                name: "po.number",
                type: "select"
            },
        ]
    } );    

    // Activate an inline edit on click of a table cell
    $('#edit_tanks').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
        editor.inline( this );
    } );

    var table = $('#edit_tanks').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        ajax: {
            url: "api/edit_tanks/?format=datatables",
            data: { 
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"
            }
        },
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        language: {
            search: "_INPUT_",
            searchPlaceholder: "Search..."
        },

        "columns": [
            {
                data: null,
                defaultContent: '',
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                orderable: false
            },
            {"data": "tag"},
            {"data": "description"},
            {"data": "pid", "number": "pid.number"},
            {"data": "zone", "number": "zone.number"},
            {"data": "medium", "code": "medium.code"},
            {"data": "revision", "code": "revision.code"},
            {"data": "supplier", "name": "supplier.name"},
            {"data": "po", "number": "po.number"},
            {"data": "material", "name": "material.name"},
            {"data": "volume"},
            {"data": "hight"},
            {"data": "modified_date"},
            {"data": "updated_by", "last_name": "user.last_name"},
        ],
        autoFill: {
            columns: ':not(:first-child)',
            editor:  editor
        },
        keys: {
            columns: ':not(:first-child)',
            editor:  editor
        },
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child',
            blurable: true
        },
        buttons: [ 
            { extend: "create", editor: editor},
            { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
            {
                extend: "selected",
                text: 'Duplicate',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    // Start in edit mode, and then change to create
                    editor
                        .edit( table.rows( {selected: true} ).indexes(), {
                            title: 'Duplicate record',
                            buttons: 'Create from existing'
                        } )
                        .mode( 'create' );
                }
            },
            { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
            ]
    });

});

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

When I try edit or inline editing i get the

> error 404  JSON: {"detail": "Not found."}

When i replace `pk` in the ajax url with a specific number, then i get

> error 400

and JSON complains that all fields are required when they are not!

I've been stuck at this point for a while, and i can't find an answer that solves my problem.... any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help someone....

In Datatables, when handling the CRUD methods on the Client-Side and using the Django Rest Framwork api, we need to point the right method to the right url, which means:

- Use the "list url" for `POST` and `GET` a list (since we are not handing a single existing instance), so in my case the url would be `url: 'api/edit_tanks/'`
- User the "detail url" for `PUT`, `DELETE` and `GET` an instance (need to pass the `pk` to identify the instance), in AJAX `_id_` can be used to get the `pk` in the url. So my url would be : `url: 'api/edit_tanks/_id_'`

This should solve the error:

> {"detail": "Not found."}

For the "fields are required" error, make sure to specify in the serializer `required=False` in all the fields that are not required. I personally specify it in all fields and let the model handle the requirements.

***About the Views (API views):***

The `ModelViewSet` already includes all the CRUD methods, can always be overridden to add new parameters or own specific logic. My view becomes:

```
class TankViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tank.objects.all().order_by('tag')
    serializer_class = TankSerializer
```